# Display multiple query results java

Tags: java

Ok, so I'm having some difficulties in returning multiple results on this query in Java

```
public String getActive() throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = DBConnect.getConnection();

    String numeUser = "";

    String sql=("select NUME from agents WHERE ACTIV = ? AND FILIALA = ? ");

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
    pstmt.setString(2, "MS10");
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next())
    {
        numeUser = rs.getString("NUME");
    }

    rs.close();
    con.close();

    return numeUser;
}
```

I heard something about that i can return the result with split() method or tokenizer but I don't seem to return the right result.

```
Agenti q2 = new Agenti();

    String str1 = q2.getActive();
    StringTokenizer stk1 = new StringTokenizer(str1);

    String[] s1 = new String[0];

    int i = 0;

    while(stk1.hasMoreElements())
    {
        s1[i] = (String) stk1.nextElement();
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(s1[0]);
```

This is my tokenizer code. Can someone help me a little, please?

Comment: What do you expect the tokenizer code to print? How is it connected to the  first block of code? I suspect that you just need to store the query results in a list rather that overwriting the the same variable again and again

Comment: do you want to select values from multiple rows in your table or do you want to extract a substring from the one value that you read from the database?

Comment: the second one with the substring

Comment: bradimus, sorry dude, i'm practically new to Java. :D